# Integral in c code, numerical method

Tags: c, numerical-methods

In college, i have a subject that is name numerical method, we mainly solve engineering tasks on c code. I have a problem with new task which i must to prepare.

The normal distribution curve is given by the equation:

```
F(x)= (1/(delta*sqrt(2*pi)))* e^-(((x-2)^2)/(2*delta^2)))
```

Where:

- `M` - average value
- `Delta` - standard deviation

Solve: 
Integral from `(m-(k*delta))` to `(m+(k*delta))` on `f(x)dx`
`k=1,..., 6`,

Solve used integration method. Determine the integration precision based on the comparison of the obtained value with the exact value. Return a result in the table in notepad file.

I wrote a first few line and a function `f(x)`, but now I don't have any idea how to write a integral and rest of the program with this part of comparation.

Could you help me?

I have this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"

Void fun(float m, float s, float d)
 F=(1/s*(2*PI)**-1)*sqrt(exp((pow(d-m,2)/2*pow(d,2)));
 Return f;

Void main(void)
 FILE *file1;
 file1=fopen("file.dat","wt");
 Printf("give me m, s,d"/n);
 Scanf("%f,%f,%f",&m,&s,&d/n);
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to do some Numerical Integration (see, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) or [these University of Cambridge course notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/people/sd/lectures/nummeth98/integration.htm)) to get the approximation.

Comment: Unless they specified more on what kind of integration method, could you not just preform a Riemann sum over the integral bounds with fixed width for each iteration of k = 1,...,6?

Comment: If it will be work it is good idea, and are there few results at end, every depends of k? How to write this integration in c?

Comment: Refresh your memory of calculus by reading up on [Riemann Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). Riemann sums, implemented, can only approximate the area within the bounds to some error.

Comment: `erf()`. You're welcome.